# What is prev(X) if X is the iterator S.begin() for some ordered container S, e.g. S is a set?

Tags: c++, iterator, set

What is `prev(X)` if `X` is the iterator `S.begin()` for some ordered container `S`, e.g. `S` is a `set`? I was expecting it to become `S.end()`, but this doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: Why do you expect `end` to be before `begin`? Iterators don't "wrap around".

Comment: The behavior is undefined if a non-decrementable iterator (such as the front iterator) is decremented.

Comment: @p0pa You could turn that into a decent answer, e.g. by just adding a link to some appropriate documentation (or even standard...).

Answer (score 2):

This causes undefined behaviour.
From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance):

> The behavior is undefined if the specified sequence of increments or decrements would require that a non-incrementable iterator (such as the past-the-end iterator) is incremented, or that a non-decrementable iterator (such as the front iterator or the singular iterator) is decremented.

Comment: It might be `S.end()` as a manifestation of undefined behavior. Especially likely for std::list if `end` is implement as sentinel node.

Comment: The first two sentences contradict each other.